# Mongoose extract first subarray element after filtering

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

I have array in subdocument like this

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("512e28984815cbfcb21646a7"),
    "descDay" : [
        {
            "language" : "en",
            "desc": "day description"
        },
        {
            "language" : "es",
            "desc": "descripcion del dia"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to filter the subdocuments by language. I can do that like this

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { $project: {
        descDay: {$filter: {
            input: '$list',
            as: 'item',
            cond: {$gt: ['$$item.language', 'en']}
        }}
    }}
])
```

that would give me something like

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("512e28984815cbfcb21646a7"),
   "descDay" : [
      {
        "language" : "en",
        "desc": "day description"
       }]
}
```

but I need descDay to be a document not an array, something like this:

```
   {
      "_id" : ObjectId("512e28984815cbfcb21646a7"),
       "descDay" : 
          {
            "language" : "en",
            "desc": "day description"
           }
    }
```

how can I get that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) to unwind the single-element `descDay` array into an object:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { $project: {
        descDay: {$filter: {
            input: '$descDay',
            as: 'item',
            cond: {$eq: ['$$item.language', 'en']}
        }}
    }},
    { $unwind: '$descDay' }
])
```

Or, as @chridam mentioned, you can use [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#exp._S_arrayElemAt) in the `$project` and directly project the first element:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { $project: {descDay: {$arrayElemAt: [
        {$filter: {
            input: '$descDay',
            as: 'item',
            cond: {$eq: ['$$item.language', 'en']}
        }}, 0]
    }}}
])
```

Either way the output is:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("512e28984815cbfcb21646a7"), 
    "descDay" : {
        "language" : "en", 
        "desc" : "day description"
    }
}
```

Note that I had to fix a couple problems in your original query:

1. `'$list'` to `'$descDay'`
2. `$gt` to `$eq`